# How to create a new category within the post form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a new blog category in the blog post form only when the new blog post does not match the listed categories. I am creating two form_for methods in rails but it shows errors.
How to implement this on ruby on rails.

I am expecting the output as, if we are creating a blog post, suppose our post matching category is not listed in the select. we need need to create a new category at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). If you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :category` in your `Post` model, you'll be able to use [`fields_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) in your post form. You didn't paste any code so this may not work without some adjustments for your specific Rails app, but you'd generally end up with a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @post do |post_form| %>
  Title: <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
  (...other post fields here...)
  <%= fields_for :category, @post.category do |category_fields| %>
    Category Title: <%= category_fields.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= post_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Depending on your use case you may want to set `@post.category` to `Category.new` in your controller, and you'll want to whitelist the nested parameters in your controller if you're using strong params. See [Nested Forms on Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) for an example of this. You'll also want handle selecting an existing category separately from this.